# LINQ-to-objects index within a group + for different groupings (aka ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION BY equivalent)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects, row-number

After much Google searching and code experimentation, I'm stumped on a complex C# LINQ-to-objects problem which in SQL would be easy to solve with a pair of ROW_NUMBER()...PARTITION BY functions and a subquery or two.

Here's, in words, what I'm trying to do in code-- the underlying requirement is removing duplicate documents from a list:

1. First, group a list by (Document.Title, Document.SourceId), assuming a (simplified) class definition like this:

   ```
   class Document
   {
       string Title;
       int SourceId; // sources are prioritized (ID=1 better than ID=2)
   }
   ```
2. Within that group, assign each document an index (e.g. Index 0 == 1st document with this title from this source, Index 1 = 2nd document with this title from this source, etc.).  I'd love the equivalent of ROW_NUMBER() in SQL!
3. Now group by (Document.Title, Index), where Index was computed in Step #2.  For each group, return only one document: the one with the lowest Document.SourceId.

Step #1 is easy (e.g. codepronet.blogspot.com/2009/01/group-by-in-linq.html), but I'm getting stumped on steps #2 and #3.  I can't seem to build a red-squiggle-free C# LINQ query to solve all three steps.

Anders Heilsberg's post on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/54f6ac70-e74c-4d9d-a9ee-6373714c0755/) is I think the answer to Steps #2 and #3 above if I could get the syntax right.

I'd prefer to avoid using an external local variable to do the Index computation, as recommended on slodge.blogspot.com/2009/01/adding-row-number-using-linq-to-objects.html, since that solution breaks if the external variable is modified.

Optimally, the group-by-Title step could be done first, so the "inner" groupings (first by Source to compute the index, then by Index to filter out duplicates) can operate on small numbers of objects in each "by title" group, since the # of documents in each by-title group is usually under 100.  I really don't want an N<sup>2</sup> solution!

I could certainly solve this with nested foreach loops, but it seems like the kind of problem which should be simple with LINQ.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think jpbochi missed that you want your groupings to be by pairs of values (Title+SourceId then Title+Index). Here's a LINQ query (mostly) solution:

```
var selectedFew = 
    from doc in docs
    group doc by new { doc.Title, doc.SourceId } into g
    from docIndex in g.Select((d, i) => new { Doc = d, Index = i })
    group docIndex by new { docIndex.Doc.Title, docIndex.Index } into g
    select g.Aggregate((a,b) => (a.Doc.SourceId <= b.Doc.SourceId) ? a : b);
```

First we group by Title+SourceId (I use an anonymous type because the compiler builds a good hashcode for the grouping lookup). Then we use Select to attach the grouped index to the document, which we use in our second grouping. Finally, for each group we pick the lowest SourceId.

Given this input:

```
var docs = new[] {
    new { Title = "ABC", SourceId = 0 },
    new { Title = "ABC", SourceId = 4 },
    new { Title = "ABC", SourceId = 2 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 7 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 7 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 7 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 5 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 5 },
};
```

I get this output:

```
{ Doc = { Title = ABC, SourceId = 0 }, Index = 0 }
{ Doc = { Title = 123, SourceId = 5 }, Index = 0 }
{ Doc = { Title = 123, SourceId = 5 }, Index = 1 }
{ Doc = { Title = 123, SourceId = 7 }, Index = 2 }
```

**Update:** I just saw your question about grouping by Title first. You can do this using a subquery on your Title groups:

```
var selectedFew =
    from doc in docs
    group doc by doc.Title into titleGroup
    from docWithIndex in
        (
            from doc in titleGroup
            group doc by doc.SourceId into idGroup
            from docIndex in idGroup.Select((d, i) => new { Doc = d, Index = i })
            group docIndex by docIndex.Index into indexGroup
            select indexGroup.Aggregate((a,b) => (a.Doc.SourceId <= b.Doc.SourceId) ? a : b)
        )
    select docWithIndex;
```

Comment: Hey DahlbyK - this is great! Your solution looks good. Now I don't feel so bad about being unable to figure it out myself the first time. I discovered the Select-with-index overload but couldn't figure out how to get it into a LINQ query. Some black-belt code on your end, thanks for the help and the education in what's possible.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I'm quite confused with your question. Maybe if you should explain what you're trying to solve. Anyway, I'll try to answer what I understood.

1) First, I'll assume that you already have a list of documents grouped by `Title`+`SourceId`. For testing purposes, I hardcoded a list as follow:

```
var docs = new [] {
    new { Title = "ABC", SourceId = 0 },
    new { Title = "ABC", SourceId = 4 },
    new { Title = "ABC", SourceId = 2 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 7 },
    new { Title = "123", SourceId = 5 },
};
```

2) To get put a index in every item, you can use the `Select` extension method, passing a Func selector function. Like this:

```
var docsWithIndex
    = docs
    .Select( (d, i) => new { Doc = d, Index = i } );
```

3) From what I understood, the next step would be to group the last result by `Title`. Here's how to do it:

```
var docsGroupedByTitle
    = docsWithIndex
    .GroupBy( a => a.Doc.Title );
```

The GroupBy function (used above) returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,DocumentWithIndex>>`. Since a group is enumerable too, we now have an enumerable of enumerables.

4) Now, for each of the groups above, we'll get only the item with the minimum `SourceId`. To make this operation we'll need 2 levels of recursion. In LINQ, the outer level is a selection (for each group, get one of its items), and the inner level is an aggregation (get the item with the lowest `SourceId`):

```
var selectedFew
    = docsGroupedByTitle
    .Select(
        g => g.Aggregate(
            (a, b) => (a.Doc.SourceId  <= b.Doc.SourceId) ? a : b
        )
    );
```

Just to ensure that it works, I tested it with a simple `foreach`:

```
foreach (var a in selectedFew) Console.WriteLine(a);
//The result will be:
//{ Doc = { Title = ABC, SourceId = 0 }, Index = 0 }
//{ Doc = { Title = 123, SourceId = 5 }, Index = 4 }
```

I'm not sure that's what you wanted. If not, please comment the answer and I can fix the answer. I hope this helps.

Obs.: All the classes used in my tests were [anonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). So, you don't really need to define a `DocumentWithIndex` type. Actually, I haven't even declared a `Document` class.

Comment: Hi jpochi - dahlby's solution was a correct one. sorry I wasn't able to get back to you sooner to clarify, this was my first question on stack overflow and I never expected to get 2 answers in less than 2 hours on a Sunday!  Next time I'll check back faster!  :-)  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Method Based Syntax:**

```
var selectedFew = docs.GroupBy(doc => new {doc.Title, doc.SourceId}, doc => doc)
                      .SelectMany((grouping) => grouping.Select((doc, index) => new {doc, index}))
                              .GroupBy(anon => new {anon.doc.Title, anon.index})
                              .Select(grouping => grouping.Aggregate((a, b) =>    a.doc.SourceId <= b.doc.SourceId ? a : b));
```

Would you say the above is the equivalent Method based syntax?

Comment: Yep, this emits the same (correct) results as DahlbyK's LINQ-y syntax above. Although (see Dahlby's updated query) it's probably more efficient to group by Title first so any sorting/aggregating can happen on tiny sets-- if there were a billion documents it'd make a big difference since you wouldn't have to load all of them into RAM at once.  Plus, most titles won't have any duplicates at all...  I hope the BCL optimzed sorting and group-by operations on one-member sets. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an extension method. It supports multiple partition by fields as well as multiple order conditions.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Partition<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>> sorter,
    Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
{
    AssertUtilities.ArgumentNotNull(source, "source");

    return source
        .GroupBy(keySelector)
        .Select(arg => sorter(arg).Select(selector))
        .SelectMany(arg => arg);
}
```

Usage:

```
var documents = new[] 
{
    new { Title = "Title1", SourceId = 1 },
    new { Title = "Title1", SourceId = 2 },
    new { Title = "Title2", SourceId = 15 },
    new { Title = "Title2", SourceId = 14 },
    new { Title = "Title3", SourceId = 100 }
};

var result = documents
    .Partition(
        arg => arg.Title,  // partition by
        arg => arg.OrderBy(x => x.SourceId), // order by
        (arg, rowNumber) => new { RowNumber = rowNumber, Document = arg }) // select
    .Where(arg => arg.RowNumber == 0)
    .Select(arg => arg.Document)
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
{ Title = "Title1", SourceId = 1 },
{ Title = "Title2", SourceId = 14 },
{ Title = "Title3", SourceId = 100 }
```